# How to remove the dots in eclipse projects?

Tags: android

I am working on android projects using Eclipse IDE. Since two days my files are opening with all dots and symbols. Can you please tell us what is the reason for that? How to remove those symbols?
[image]

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `Window` menu `Prefrences` + `Editors` + `Text Editors` + Unchecked the `Show Whitespace characters`.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

[image]

Comment: How.. explain that here as well and if some answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions and configure it to remove trailing whitespace