# Issue with eclipse appearance

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

Dots are appearing after every line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before and what fixed it for me was refreshing the project, cleaning project, and restarting eclipse. Let me know if it works.

Comment: weird problem, when I did all this, every thing gone, then I press ctrl+shift+/ to collapse all code then open the desired one then this appears again. Then I press ctrl+shift+* to un collapse all then these dots again disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try different options which are discussed in below SO Link.
[How to remove the dots in eclipse projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564628/how-to-remove-the-dots-in-eclipse-projects)

Good Luck!!